# Get all threads launched by external methods

Tags: c#, multithreading

Assume we have a C# application that supports a plugin mechanism, and each plugin must implement an API (**which cannot be changed**).

- The plugin is called several times during the application process (e.g. at startup, at application exit...).
- The plugin might launch an unknown number of threads
- We don't have access to the plugin methods

**The problem:**

How can we make sure that after our application has exited (or at any other time for that matter), all the threads that the plugin launched won't remain alive? Is there a way to get all the "child" threads of the thread that launched the plugin?

Notes:

- I tried to use Thread.Abort() on the thread that launched the plugin, but it didn't abort all the created threads
- I don't want to iterate over all the existing threads of the application process, since there are some threads (not related to the plugin) that needs to stay alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Environment.Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit) method to terminate the process.

> Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are running.

Be aware that if you kill the process this way, and there is code executing in a `try` block, the `finally` block will **not** be executed.